# Problem in the E2E tests of Vue.js, Nigthwatch, Selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, vue.js, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run e2e tests from a Vue.js application in a docker container.

The nightwatch configuration file looks like this:

*nightwatch.json*

```
{
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["disable-web-security", "ignore-certificate-errors", "headless"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this image in the container: [pijzl/vuejs-docker-unit-e2e](https://hub.docker.com/r/pijzl/vuejs-docker-unit-e2e)

When running at the physical machine prompt the tests pass, however when running in docker I encounter the following error:

> Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
>
> Connection refused! Is selenium server started? { value:    { message:
>   'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (unknown
>   error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn\'t exist)\n  (The process started
>   from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.46.628388
>   (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux
>   4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 597
>   milliseconds\nBuild info: version: \'3.141.59\', revision:
>   \'e82be7d358\', time: \'2018-11-14T08:25:53\'\nSystem info: host:
>   \'df8c8d010486\', ip: \'172.17.0.2\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch:
>   \'amd64\', os.version: \'4.9.125-linuxkit\', java.version:
>   \'1.8.0_171\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown',
>        error: 'unknown error' },   status: 13 }

Anyone have any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: what docker command do you run to start the tests? from which docker image?

Comment: @Thomasleveil 
I updated the question with the image url, and I am using the standard command to run ```yarn test:e2e``` (vue-cli-service test:e2e) with docker ```docker run -it --rm -p 8081:8080 -v "$PWD":"$PWD" -w "$PWD" --name "vuejs-docker-unit-e2e" -it pijzl/vuejs-docker-unit-e2e:latest yarn test:e2e```